# Javascript: Image cropping for every Device Pixel Ratio

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

```js
function removeImageBlanks(imageObject, padding, cornerRadius) {
  var imgWidth = imageObject.width;
  var imgHeight = imageObject.height;

  // Calculate canvas dimensions with device pixel ratio
  var canvasWidth = imgWidth;
  var canvasHeight = imgHeight;

  // Create canvas element with device pixel ratio
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = canvasWidth;
  canvas.height = canvasHeight;

  // Set canvas display size with CSS to ensure correct rendering on high-density displays
  canvas.style.width = imgWidth + 'px';
  canvas.style.height = imgHeight + 'px';

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  // Scale the context by the device pixel ratio
  context.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);

  context.drawImage(imageObject, 0, 0);

  var imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  var data = imageData.data;

  var getRGB = function(x, y) {
    var offset = imgWidth * y + x;
    return {
      red: data[offset * 4],
      green: data[offset * 4 + 1],
      blue: data[offset * 4 + 2],
      opacity: data[offset * 4 + 3]
    };
  };
  var isWhite = function(rgb) {
    // Many images contain noise, as the white is not a pure #fff white
    return rgb.red > 200 && rgb.green > 200 && rgb.blue > 200;
  };
  var scanY = function(fromTop) {
    var offset = fromTop ? 1 : -1;

    // Loop through each row
    for (var y = fromTop ? 0 : imgHeight - 1; fromTop ? (y < imgHeight) : (y > -1); y += offset) {

      // Loop through each column
      for (var x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
        var rgb = getRGB(x, y);
        if (!isWhite(rgb)) {
          if (fromTop) {
            return y;
          } else {
            return Math.min(y + 1, imgHeight);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null; // All image is white
  };
  var scanX = function(fromLeft) {
    var offset = fromLeft ? 1 : -1;

    // Loop through each column
    for (var x = fromLeft ? 0 : imgWidth - 1; fromLeft ? (x < imgWidth) : (x > -1); x += offset) {

      // Loop through each row
      for (var y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
        var rgb = getRGB(x, y);
        if (!isWhite(rgb)) {
          if (fromLeft) {
            return x;
          } else {
            return Math.min(x + 1, imgWidth);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null; // All image is white
  };
```

Basically, what's happening is that the image size is not consistent throughout various device pixel ratios (1x... 2x... 3x...) and it only works properly at 1x.

What I am trying to do, is to remove the whitespace of the image surrounding the object in the centre as much as possible.

If anyone could give me an insight into what's wrong in this code, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: why solve it depending on the DPR instead of the viewport?

Comment: @tacoshy viewport? how should i fix this code, then? The image basically is cropped inconsistently when DPR changes.

Comment: How dobyou call tjese functions? Currently only the image is drawn on the context and getRGB, isWhite,etc. are never called.

Comment: @Kaiido https://www.npmjs.com/package/intelli-image-crop Check this NPM package I made. Read the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by multiplying the DPR ratio to the canvas before processing the image (auto-cropping).

```js
// Rasterize the canvas
      const rasterizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// Below lines were edited...
      rasterizedCanvas.width = viewerCanvas.offsetWidth * props.devicePixelRatio;
      rasterizedCanvas.height = viewerCanvas.offsetHeight * props.devicePixelRatio;
      const rasterizedContext = rasterizedCanvas.getContext("2d");
      rasterizedContext.drawImage(viewerCanvas, 0, 0);
  
      const croppedDataUrl = removeImageBlanks(rasterizedCanvas, padding, cornerRadius);
```